# ¿Por qué me imprime NaN en java?

Tags: java, imprimir

Estoy tratando de hacer un método de resoluciones de ecuaciones pero al imprimir me hace esto:

```
El valor aproximado de P es: NaN
0.0*(NaN)^2+(0.0)(NaN)+(0.0)= NaN
```

Traté de acortar el número de decimales a imprimir con `DecimalFormat` pero no funcionó.
Quizá esté haciendo mal el método pero no puedo saberlo si no me imprime los valores que necesito ver para confirmarlo, así que primero me gustaría solucionar el `NaN`. Agradecería su ayuda.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class reglaslsa23 {
    static double a,b,c,x,p,inicio,fin;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            ecuacion(a,b,c,p,inicio,fin);
            metodo(x,a,b,c,p,inicio,fin);
    }
    
    public static void ecuacion (double a, double b,double c,double p,double inicio,double fin) {
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in)) {
            System.out.println("Añade a,b y c.");
            a=sc.nextDouble();
            b=sc.nextDouble();
            c=sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Añade el intervalo");
            inicio=sc.nextDouble();
            fin=sc.nextDouble();
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Por favor, ingrese un dato valido");   
        }
    }
    public static double f(double x,double a, double b,double c) {
        return (a*x*x)+(b*x)+c;
    }
    public static void metodo (double x,double a, double b,double c,double p,double inicio,double fin) {
        int contador = 1;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0000");
        if (f(inicio,a,b,c)*f(fin,a,b,c)>0) {
            System.out.println("No se cumple que f(a)*f(b)<0. Pruebe otro intervalo.");
            return;
        } else {
        do {
            p = (((f(fin,a,b,c)*inicio)-(f(inicio,a,b,c)*fin))/((f(fin,a,b,c)-(f(inicio,a,b,c)))));
                System.out.println("El valor aproximado de P es: "+ df.format(p));
                System.out.print(a+"*("+p+")^2+("+b+")("+p+")+("+c+")= ");
                System.out.println(df.format(f(p,a,b,c)));
            if (f(inicio,a,b,c)*f(p,a,b,c)<0) {
                fin = p;
            } else {
                inicio = p;
            }
            contador++;
        } while (contador <10);
            
        }}}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Para poder reproducir tu problema necesitamos dos cosas: la implementación del método `f` y algún valor de prueba de los parámetros de la función que generan el valor `NaN`.

Comment: Un número de coma flotante puede ser `NaN` por diferentes motivos (por ejemplo, una conversión desde un texto inadecuado, en cuyo caso el problema está fuera del método que compartes), pero para saber el motivo exacto de tu problema se necesitan los datos que te he solicitado (`f()` y parámetros de entrada).

Comment: que es la funcion `f`??? `f(a,b,c,inicio)` Agregala por favor

Comment: Hola Derek, si saber que debe hacer tu método y desconociendo el método **f**, se complica... ahora bien, yo he implementado un método **f** bobo, que solo suma los parámetros recibidos, y con los valores adecuados, no me genera ningún **NaN**, ademas de pasarnos el código que falta, constata que parámetros le estás enviando a **metodo**.

Comment: Muestra como llamas la función `metodo`.

Comment: Listo. He añadido más código, agradezco sus comentarios.

Comment: Por favor, añade a tu main los valores de `a`, `b`, `c`, `inicio`, `fin` y `x` ya que eso es clave para saber qué pudo haberse mapeado a `NaN`

Comment: adicionalmente tu código está raro, ya que en ecuación se reciben parámetros que no se usan, y que además se sobreescriben con la llamada a scanner. Supongo que la idea es tomar los valores del texto de la entrada, pero si ese fuera el caso, ayudaría saber que valores pusiste en la entrada, además de corregir el código, aparentemente el código que está en `ecuación` devbería ir al principio de `main` pero aún así faltaría definir `x`

Comment: Ya veo, estás intentando cargar los valores de las variables en `ecuación` pero te recuerdo que en java los parámetros son por valor, por lo que las asignaciones que hagas dentro de `ecuación` se pierden a la salida de la función. De todos modos sigue faltando `x` ahh y `p` también

Comment: Lo que veo es que `p` que es la variable que está dándote `Nan` no la incicializas en  ningún lado, quizás si muestras como se carga podríamos ayudarte a ver por qué es `NaN` quizás

Comment: Ya he añadido el código completo, Andrés, espero te ayude de algo

Comment: Se puede arreglar el NaN, quitando **metodo** del main y lo llamas desde **ecuación**.

Answer (score 0):

Las variables claramente permanecen en 0 durante toda la ejecución del programa.

Llegado a cierto punto se produce una operación que no da un resultado válido y obtienes **NaN**.

Particularmente se produce cuando se divide 0 por 0 o cuando se intenta calcular la raíz cuadrada de un número negativo. [Más información](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2618081/13419694).

---

Al asignar una variable o pasarla como argumento a una función, se crea una copia de su contenido. De modo que la variable original no se altera.

Puede parecer contradictorio con objetos. Ya que si pasas un objeto, los cambios se ven reflejados en la variable original.

Ahí está la cuestión. Las variables de tipo **object** guardan una **referencia** (la dirección en memoria) a una **instancia**. Al copiar una variable de este tipo se crea una copia de la referencia y no de la instancia.

---

Dicho esto, los campos de la línea

```
static double a,b,c,x,p,inicio,fin;
```

Son ocultados por los parámetros de la función:

```
public static void ecuacion (double a, double b,double c,double p,double inicio,double fin)
```

La solución más simple es quitar los parámetros de la función y usar directamente los campos estáticos:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ecuacion();
    metodo();
}

public static void ecuacion() {
    // ...
}

public static void metodo() {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema se debe a que estás utilizando las variables a, b y c en el método ecuacion antes de haberles asignado un valor. En Java, las variables locales se inicializan automáticamente en su valor predeterminado, que es 0.0 para los tipos numéricos como double, por lo que a, b y c tienen un valor de 0.0 al inicio del programa.

Cuando llamas al método `metodo()`, pasas las variables `a`, `b` y `c` como argumentos, pero estos valores no son los mismos que los que ingresaste por teclado en el método `ecuacion()`.

Para solucionar el problema, debes llamar primero al método `ecuacion()` y asignar los valores ingresados por teclado a las variables `a`, `b` y `c`. Luego, llama al método `metodo()` con las variables actualizadas.

Aquí te dejo una posible solución al problema:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class reglaslsa23 {
    static double a,b,c,x,p,inicio,fin;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ecuacion();
        metodo();
    }
    
    public static void ecuacion() {
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in)) {
            System.out.println("Añade a,b y c.");
            a=sc.nextDouble();
            b=sc.nextDouble();
            c=sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Añade el intervalo");
            inicio=sc.nextDouble();
            fin=sc.nextDouble();
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Por favor, ingrese un dato valido");   
        }
    }
    
    public static double f(double x) {
        return (a*x*x)+(b*x)+c;
    }
    
    public static void metodo() {
        int contador = 1;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0000");
        if (f(inicio)*f(fin)>0) {
            System.out.println("No se cumple que f(a)*f(b)<0. Pruebe otro intervalo.");
            return;
        } else {
            do {
                p = (((f(fin)*inicio)-(f(inicio)*fin))/((f(fin)-(f(inicio)))));
                System.out.println("El valor aproximado de P es: "+ df.format(p));
                System.out.print(a+"*("+p+")^2+("+b+")("+p+")+("+c+")= ");
                System.out.println(df.format(f(p)));
                if (f(inicio)*f(p)<0) {
                    fin = p;
                } else {
                    inicio = p;
                }
                contador++;
            } while (contador <10);
        }
    }
}
```